# pagination illusion with jQuery

Tags: jquery, pagination

hey, i'm wanting to create a basic pagination affect.. i have (lets say) 100 posts.
i want to show the first 9, so therefore hide from 10 - 100
how do i grab those children.

my next request to have in mind is obviously to hide 1-9 show 10-18 hide 19-100
you get the idea.
thanks in advanced.

mark up along the lines of:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="widget">some content...</div>
  <div class="widget">some content...</div>
  <div class="widget">some content...</div>
  <div class="widget">some content...</div>
  <div class="widget">some content...</div>
  <div class="widget">some content...</div>
etc...
</div>
```

Comment: Based on your posts, you are using this site as a place to get others to do your coding for you. The whole point of SO is to seek help and knowledge when you need it, not have others do your dirty work because you are too lazy to do so.

Comment: @cambraca: Technically it is. He's asking us to do it for him.

Comment: come on guys!..  don't jump on me like that.. i'm not wanting a full solution at all.. just how to target/traverse to the correct nth children using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) function to restrict the selection to a range.  Note that it's zero-based.

```
$('.widget').hide().slice(9,17).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

To hide all but the first nine, you can use the `:gt` selector:

```
$(".grid .widget:gt(8)").hide();
```

You can use a combination of the [`:gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and [`:lt`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selectors to achieve your goal.

The other way I would suggest would be to use `slice` as per @tvanfosson's answer. (+1)

Comment: Thankyou!!.  this is what i wanted!!.. i don't know what all the other peoples problems are assuming that i wanted it all written out!

Comment: I think tvanfosson's `slice()` approach is better as it doesn't involve possible manually building of the selector string (I doubt anyone would hardcode the min/max values for :lt and :gt in his pagination code).

Comment: @ThiefMaster - I was just pointing out those selectors by example rather than providing a complete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code. Obviously you'll want to set `page` and then execute the `each()` code whenever the user changes the page.

```
var ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 2;
var page = 1;

// Option 1
$('.grid > .widget').each(function(i, item) {
    var visible = i >= (ITEMS_PER_PAGE * (page - 1)) && i < (ITEMS_PER_PAGE * page);
    $(item).toggle(visible);
});

// Option 2 (based on other answers)
$('.grid > .widget').hide().slice((ITEMS_PER_PAGE * (page - 1)), (ITEMS_PER_PAGE * page)).show();
```

Comment: Thanks, have you found using the less than greater than sign to have problems with older versions of ie??  my client requires ie6 compatability.

Comment: It's very unlikely. However, you might want to try putting your javascript in a CDATA or HTML comment section - or simply load it from an external file.